# TypeError: Collection is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js'); 
const Collection = require('discord.js'); 
const Client = require('discord.js'); 
const fs = require('fs');
const bot = new Discord.Client({
  disableEveryone: true
});
bot.commands = new Collection();
bot.aliases = new Collection();
```

If this is not enough tell me I will send more but the error is on those lines. Thanks.

Comment: your `Collection` is NOT a constructor function, so you can't use the `new` keyword with it.

Comment: co just `bot.commands = Collection();`?

Comment: your `Collection` & `Client` is the same object as your `Discord` why did you create them, or is this just an example

Comment: for command handler, is there a diffrence between `const Discord = require('discord.js'); 
                 const Collection = require('discord.js'); 
                 const Client = require('discord.js'); `  and  `const {Discord, Collection, Client} = require('discord.js')`??

Comment: yes it's different, you should use `const { Collection, Client } = require('discord.js')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not importing discord.js correctly.

Either import discord.js completely and access `Collection()` through it.

```js
const Discord = require ('discord.js')

bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();
bot.aliases = new Discord.Collection()
```

Or just import what you need:

```js
const { Client, Collection } = require ('discord.js')

bot.commands = new Collection();
bot.aliases = new Collection()
```